# How to browse ESLint errors in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I have to run `eslint` by hand every time (via `npm run lint`, for example) and then scroll problems in the terminal, which is not convenient. I would prefer instead to get warnings and errors right in my IDE UI. How can I get that?

I have ESLint VSCode extension installed but it doesn't seem like it provides any lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That plugin should highlight any lint issues in files you have open.

Any errors or warnings in any file that is open will appear in the "problems" pane.

[image: VSCode Problems Pane]

---

To be clear, here's how I use lining in my projects.  I use Angular, so I run `ng lint` and errors are reported in the terminal.  **I can then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click on an file path, or specific lint error to be taken directly there!**

Any open files will report lint errors in the "Problems" pane.

If I have a lot of lint issues to get though I can just open files one-by-one via the terminal, fix the files until the problems pane is clear, then move to the next file. I only need to run the command line once really.

[image: VSCode Linting]

My guess is that you can't just have the entire project linting going on at all times for the entire project because that would be too process intensive. But just monitoring the open files is fine since that has a limited scope.

---

## Update from Comments

Enable the `eslint.lintTask.enable` option in VSCode's settings for this plugin, which will create a `tasks.json` file with a task called `eslint: lint whole folder`. Running this task will lint the entire project AND populate the "Problems" tab.

Binding `workbench.action.tasks.runTask` to a key combination is a good idea to be able to quickly lint a project.

Comment: Yeah, but the question is how to run ESlint?

Comment: What do you mean?  With the plugin it automatically runs on any file that it open in the UI and all lint issues show up in this window.  If you want to "run" eslint on everything, then use the command line.  As far as I know there isn't a way to get this view for all files...unless of course you just opened up every file.  My suggestion is auto fix all auto-fixable issues, then open each file and fix the issues one by one.

Comment: That's the thing. You have to open the terminal and run `npm run lint` or whatever manually in the command line every time. I would prefer a way to run it against all the files in the project. But the `Problems` section is very good, I didn't know about it, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Problems tab doesn't get updated when you just run `eslint`. Even if it found problems the file tree doesn't get updated, files and directories are not getting red. So literally nothing happens, you have only a list of problems in the terminal output. :(

Comment: Here is a link with a demonstration of what I'm talking about: https://i.imgur.com/oIA05bw.png

Comment: 2 things: You do realize that you can Ctrl+click on those file paths in the terminal and that will open up those files, right?  Check out [the options for the ESLint plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint#settings-options), that might actually be able to do more than you (and I!) initially thought

Comment: See my updated answer. I think you might need to switch to using a better Lint reporter that shows you more details about the issues instead of just listing the files

Comment: Yeah, thank you, I do ctrl-click on files :) Yeah, a bunch of options. Need to try them out.

Comment: After reading the docs and playing with configuration, I came up with the following setup. I enabled the `eslint.lintTask.enable` option, which created `tasks.json` in my workspace with a task labled `eslint: lint whole folder`. Now when I run this task, the entire project gets linted AND populating the "Problems" tab. I also bound `workbench.action.tasks.runTask` to `Ctrl+'` so now it's done with one gesture. You could try this and update the answer. Thanks for pointing me out to the docs :)

Comment: There is one more useful feature of making it a task: when you're fixing issues, the Problems content is updated automatically, so you don't need to rerun the task.

Comment: That's super cool, I suspected that could work but I never tried it before. We both learned something new here!  I've updated my answer to include what you discovered so future people don't have to read though all these comments